# How Grep Conditional matches works?

Tags: grep

---

Here I am practicing the grep commands .Am not clear with the following grep condition how it works?

a_file:

```
boot
record
boots
process
broken
commands
```

I had tried the following commands :-

```
1. grep -A0 "boo" a_file

result:
boot
--
boots

2.grep -A1 "boo" a_file
result:
boot
record
boots
process

3.grep -A2 "boo" a_file
result:
boot
record
boots
process
broken

4.grep -A3 "boo" a_file
result:
boot
record
boots
process
broken
commands

Note:I had studied this grep command from terminal man grep.
```

My Query:

```
1.What is the purpose of switch -A?
2.How the context lines are ordered for every numeric values (i.e 1,2,3)?
```

Comment: What do you try to understand for your 2nd question? How does `grep -A` implement its job?

Comment: A denotes after matching context.If I give A2 it will look for searching string(i.e boo).After that matching line due to A2 it will print next two lines after the matching string.This is what I understood from the command. @CWLiu

Comment: Yes, your understand is basically right, and what's your second question, Elaborate it. That would help guys here to offer you more precise answer.

Comment: Until how many numbers we can use along with A .Should it be used in any order.That is my second questions @CWLiu

Comment: Until how many numbers we can use along with A .Should it be used in any order.That is my second questions @CWLiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, `-A` or `-B` is really useful while you dubug a long and complex log. You are allowed to use `-A` and `-B` option to see more details behind and before the searched pattern in the log also speed up the debug efficiency.

For your second question, from the [src](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/grep.git) of `grep`, there's no specific limitation for option `-A`. The argument of it ,i.e. `out_after`, is defined as an `long int` in the src.

```
static intmax_t out_after;  /* Lines of trailing context. */
```

I assume that the trailing lines to be printed until EOF or next matched pattern is hit (the count of trailing line would be reset).